# Agda: Cannot Instantiate Metavariable

Tags: agda, cubical-agda, errors

I'm running into a certain error while trying to code something up in cubical Agda, but I can't understand the error. Here is my code:

```
liftFam' : {A : Type} {x y : A} {B : A → Type} (u : B x) (p : x ≡ y) → (x , u) ≡ (y , (transp (λ i → B (p i)) i0) u)
liftFam' u p = {!!}
```

But, I get the following error upon trying to load the document:

```
Cannot instantiate the metavariable _219 to solution B (p i1)
since it contains the variable p
which is not in scope of the metavariable
when checking that the expression transp (λ i → B (p i)) i0 u has
type _B_219 y
```

Can anybody give some advice on what the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL; DR: Explicitly stating the type of the equality solves the problem:

```hs
_≡_ {A = Σ _ B} (x , u) (y , transp (λ i → B (p i)) i0 u)
```

I think the main problem is that Agda is confused about the type of the dependent pair (which should be `Σ A B`, but you didn't in any way indicate that). In usual cases Agda should infer that by looking at the types on both sides of the equality. The further complication of `transp` completely threw Agda off, so it is reporting something seemingly unrelated to the core error.

Comment: `_≡_ {A = Σ _ B}` is more neatly written `Path (Σ _ B)`.

Comment: @HTNW Right, I forgot we are in cubical Agda.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from @Trebor's answer, there is another way to specify the implicit argument:

```
(x , u) ≡ (_,_ {B = B} y (transp (λ i → B (p i)) i0 u))
```

You may also remove the parentheses on the right hand side:

```
(x , u) ≡ _,_ {B = B} y (transp (λ i → B (p i)) i0 u)
```